# Why am I trying to calculate $\int \frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx$ using integration by parts, but it only gets harder

Tags: integration

I need to calculate: $\int \frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx$
I use the formula: $\int udv=uv - \int vdu$, then I get:
$u=\ln x; \; du=u' ⋅ dx=(\ln x)'⋅dx=\frac{dx}{x};$
$dv= \frac{dx}{x};v=\int \frac{dx}{x}=\ln{|x|};$

$$\int u\,dv=\ln{x} \cdot \ln{|x|} - \int { \frac{\ln{|x|} \cdot dx}{x}}$$

In fact, I received only the complication of my task.

Comment: try substitution with $u = \ln x$

Comment: Yes, I try: u = ln(x)

Comment: We have $x > 0$, so the absolute value is unnecessary. What your integration by parts yields is $$\int u\,dv = u^2 - \int u\,dv\,.$$ Since on the right you _subtract_ the integral you want to determine, rearrange to get $$2\int u\,dv = u^2$$ (plus a constant, of course). But it's more direct if you see that the integral is of the form $$\int f(x)\cdot f'(x)\,dx\,.$$

Comment: Hint: $\int \ln{x}d\ln{x}$

Comment: Yes, but I don't know integral ln(x)

Comment: Using the comments of Daniel Fischer, who explained to me how 2 + 2 = 4, I can understand this. Thanks!

Comment: Once again, thank you to everyone who helped me understand the solution. Sometimes, I don't immediately see something obvious. This is my problem.

Comment: @projectilemotion I have a problem with displaying formulas in comments Math SO. I see Nick’s comment as: "Hint:". I know that there is a formula, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you are forced to consider $x>0$ from start to finish, as that is the maximal domain of the logarithm in the integrand. This means that you can drop the absolute value signs when taking the antiderivative of $1/x$. You are left with 
$$
\int \frac{\ln x} x dx = (\ln x)^2 - \int \frac{\ln x} x dx,
$$
and adding $\int \frac{\ln x} x dx$ to both sides you retrieve
$$ \int \frac{\ln x} x dx = \frac 12 (\ln x)^2 + C$$
which is the correct result.

In general, you need to remember that integration by parts is not guaranteed to lead you anywhere useful; the rule of thumb is to choose $u$ and $v$ in such a way that the integral on the RHS is simpler than the one you’re trying to solve. In other cases, like this one, after a few instances of IBP you might retrieve your original integral, so you can finish off as we did. But other than these special cases, this technique alone will generally make your integral worse.

Comment: I would add your answer part from comments of Daniel Fischer

Comment: It was hard for me to understand such a simple thing as where 1/2 came from...

Comment: @Student Try carefully repeating the steps on a separate piece of paper. I skipped the one just before the final answer. Hopefully writing it down will clarify where the 1/2 comes from

Comment: To giobrach: Now Yes

Answer (score 2):

> $\int udv=\ln{x} \cdot \ln{|x|} - \int {  \frac{\ln{|x|} \cdot
>  dx}{x}}$

Basically it is $\int \frac{\ln{|x|}}{x}dx=\ln{|x|} \cdot \ln{|x|} - \int {  \frac{\ln{|x|} \cdot dx}{x}}$

Now add $\int {  \frac{\ln{|x|} }{x}}\, dx$ on both sides.

Comment: Thanks! I upvote your answer.

Comment: You´re welcome. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Derivative (lnx)^2 now you can see path

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Why ((lnx)^2)' ?

Comment: Derivative (lnx)^2  then you can see 2lnx/x then ansewer of your question is (lnx)^2/2

Comment: Some integration can be solved in our mind without using calculations

Answer (score 1):

In general $$\int \frac{\ln(x)^a}{x} \, dx = \frac{\ln(x)^{a+1}}{a+1}  +C$$