# Is this entry correct?

Tags: integration, proof-writing

When I write calculations using the integration formula in parts, [for example from the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523229/why-am-i-trying-to-calculate-int-frac-lnxxdx-using-integration-by-part/3523237), I write:

$u=\ln x; \; du=u' ⋅ \color{red}{dx}=(\ln x)'⋅dx=\frac{dx}{x};$

And something tells me it's not right, and I have to write and only so:

$u=\ln x; \; du=u' ⋅ \color{blue}{du}=(\ln x)'⋅dx=\frac{dx}{x};$

Comment: First (red) is right, second (blue) is wrong. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: $$u=\ln x \implies \frac{du}{dx}=(\ln x)'=u'\implies du=u'\cdot dx$$

and on the other hand

$$du=u'\cdot du \iff u'=1$$

is only true if $x=1$. So, the derivation made in red is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is correct, as in $u = ln(x)$ in your substitution you are basically saying $u(x) = ln(x)$. So here, after you differentiate, you differentiate **u as a function of x**. So 
$u'(x) = du/dx \implies (ln(x))' = du/dx \iff du = \frac{1}{x} dx $, where I introduced the Leibniz $du/dx = u'(x)$ to make this a bit more clear. Writing $du = u'du$ does not make much sense, as it is not clear here what do you mean by $du$ and $u'$. As I am understanding your notation, those two should mean the same thing.